# How i can get size OR ext from files in cakephp

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp

In controller:

```
    public function Attachments(){
    $this->layout = null;
    $folder = new Folder(WWW_ROOT.'/files/attachments');
    $files = $folder->find('.*\.*');
    $this->set('files', $files);}
```

In View (Attachments.ctp):

```
<?php foreach($files as $file): ?>          
   <i><?php echo $file; ?></i>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

How i can get size OR ext !?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is action in my PostController

```
public function attachments(){
        $dir = new Folder(WWW_ROOT.'files/attachments');
        $files = $dir->read(true);
        foreach ($files['1'] as $k=>$v)
        {
            $fileObj = new File(WWW_ROOT.'files/attachments/'.$v);
            $info[]=$fileObj->info();
        } 
        $this->set('info',$info);
    }
```

and below is code of attachments.ctp file

```
<?php 
foreach ($info as $k=>$v)
{
    echo $v['extension'].'<br/>';
    echo $v['filesize'].'<br/>';
}
?>
```